# How to download build artifact to local folder

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I'm using Azure Pipeline for CI, the same is configured to self hosted agent.

Question is I **want to Download the build file to the local folder of self hosted agent (eg: c:\agent\buildFolder)**

Can you guide me on the above question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, if you are running the pipeline in the self-hosted agent, and you want to download the file from `c:\agent\buildFolder` to another local folder, you can simply use the [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), just specify the `Source Folder`, `contents`, `Target Folder` you want.

```
# Copy files
# Copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths (not folder paths)
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    #sourceFolder: # Optional
    #contents: '**' 
    targetFolder: 
    #cleanTargetFolder: false # Optional
    #overWrite: false # Optional
    #flattenFolders: false # Optional
    #preserveTimestamp: false # Optional
    #retryCount: 0 # Optional
    #ignoreMakeDirErrors: false # Optional
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Joy Wang-MSFT. it is working now.

Comment: @sanjai If so, consider accepting it as the answer, it can help other community members, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work thank you.